# Pivoted MySQL table: Can I group groups and avoid results in one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I'm having trouble pivoting a table in MySQL. I've been reading trying to accomplish the result I want, and I'm almost there, but I can't see clearly what to do next.

I'm creating a report of a questionnaire. The report states the person who applied the questionare, the one who solved it and the set of questions with the answers given and some more info.

I have already a query that gives the correct info this way for every person:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════════════╗
║  supervisor   ║ zone ║   promoter   ║  visit_id ║  question  ║     answer     ║
╠═══════════════╬══════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════════╣
║ EDGAR MONTIEL ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║ Question A ║ 1              ║
║ EDGAR MONTIEL ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║ Question B ║ 1              ║
║ EDGAR MONTIEL ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║ Question C ║ Any given text ║
╚═══════════════╩══════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT` as seen in many tutorials, I've managed to pivot the report retrieving the correct info.
In a nutshell, I did it like this:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(IF(infoBase.question = \'',question,'\', \'',answer,'\', 0)) AS \'',question,'\'',''), "\n"
    ) INTO @answers
FROM (many tables)
WHERE (some expresions)
```

Then I use a prepared statement to get the final result like this:

```
SET @query := 
    CONCAT(
        'SELECT  
         infoBase.supervisor, 
         infoBase.zone, 
         infoBase.promoter,
         infoBase.visit_id,
    ',@answers,' FROM (same tables as before) WHERE (same expresions as before)'
    );
```

Then I execute the query:

```
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
```

Whilst I retrieve the info correctly, my result set looks like this:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║  supervisor   ║ zone ║   promoter   ║  visit_id ║ Question A ║ Question B ║   Question C   ║ Question A ║ Question B ║                              Question C                              ║ Question A ║ Question B ║         Question C         ║
╠═══════════════╬══════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ EDGAR MONTIEL ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║          1 ║          1 ║ Any given text ║          3 ║          3 ║ Including punctuation characters, like comma, admiration ! or dots . ║          2 ║          2 ║ Text is fun, text is life! ║
╚═══════════════╩══════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

The info is correct but it's in the same row and the first part about the people is not seen. So I try to group by `visit_id` that gives unicity, and I get this:

```
╔═════════════════╦══════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════════╗
║   supervisor    ║ zone ║   promoter   ║  visit_id ║ Question A ║ Question B ║   Question C   ║
╠═════════════════╬══════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════════╣
║ EDGAR MONTIEL   ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║          1 ║          1 ║ Any given text ║
║ NEYRA OLIVER    ║ VDM2 ║ OMAR SOTO    ║    114442 ║          1 ║          1 ║ Any given text ║
║ KAYRA RODRIGUEZ ║ GU1  ║ VICTOR SOTO  ║    114197 ║          1 ║          1 ║ Any given text ║
╚═════════════════╩══════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Now the first part of the table is correct but the second part about the questions just reflects the results of the first person in every row. I need to get the following in order to succeed:

```
╔═════════════════╦══════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   supervisor    ║ zone ║   promoter   ║  visit_id ║ Question A ║ Question B ║                              Question C                              ║
╠═════════════════╬══════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ EDGAR MONTIEL   ║ VM1  ║ MIGUEL LOPEZ ║    104285 ║          1 ║          1 ║ Any given text                                                       ║
║ NEYRA OLIVER    ║ VDM2 ║ OMAR SOTO    ║    114442 ║          3 ║          3 ║ Including punctuation characters, like comma, admiration ! or dots . ║
║ KAYRA RODRIGUEZ ║ GU1  ║ VICTOR SOTO  ║    114197 ║          2 ║          2 ║ Text is fun, text is life!                                           ║
╚═════════════════╩══════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

This is an over simplification of the real problem. The whole problem involves tens of questions for differents questionnaires. Say questionnaire 1 has 45 questions, questionnaire 2 has 30 questions, questionare 3 has 80 questions, etc. So I don't even know the exact number of questions as it varies, thus I'm trying to get this dynamically.

How can I get this result? What do I need to `group by` or what do I need to do?

Comment: I recommend you use application layer code for this dynamic, conditional need like Python, R, PHP, Perl, Java, etc. which can all connect to MySQL with great tools to reshape data. Plus your need is a reporting need anyway not for database storage so might as well be moved a layer up. Wish this was my problem. OPs get all the fun!

Comment: Best to do in client code.  But here is a [_Stored Proc to generate pivot code_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) .